# Gerar Array com valores via POST por PHP

Tags: php, json, array

Estou tentando gerar um array com valores vindos de um formulário por POST, para preencher um JSON do PAGHIPER.
Este é o Array que preciso montar:

```
$data = array(
 'apiKey' => 'MINHAKEY',
  'order_id' => rand(5, 15), // código interno do lojista para identificar a transacao
  'payer_email' => $_GET['emailResponsavel'],
  'payer_name' => $_GET['nomeResponsavel'], // nome completo ou razao social
  'payer_cpf_cnpj' => $_GET['cpfCnpjResponsavel'], // cpf ou cnpj
  'notification_url' => 'MINHA URL',
  'fixed_description' => true,
  'days_due_date' => '5', // dias para vencimento do Pix
  'items' => array(
  array ('description' => 'piscina de bolinha',
  'quantity' => '1',
  'item_id' => '1',
  'price_cents' => '1012'), // em centavos
array ('description' => 'pula pula',
  'quantity' => '2',
  'item_id' => '1',
  'price_cents' => '2000'), // em centavos
array ('description' => 'mala de viagem',
  'quantity' => '3',
  'item_id' => '1',
  'price_cents' => '4000'), // em centavos
  ),
  );
```

Notem que é um Array multidimensional, onde não estou conseguindo imprimir os valores preenchidos pelo usuário, estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

RECEBENDO OS VALORES COMPRADOS PELO USUÁRIO

```
 $item = array_map(function($value, $quantity, $item_id, $price_cents ){
    $temp['description'] = $value;
    $temp['quantity'] = $quantity;
    $temp['item_id'] = $item_id;
    $temp['price_cents'] = $price_cents;
},  $description = $_POST['description'], 
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'],
    $item_id = $_POST['item_id'], 
    $price_cents = $_POST['price_cents']);
```

Estou realmente perdido em como fazer com que os valores preenchidos pelo usuário montem este array multidimensional. Os valores que são preenchidos pelo usuário ficaram dentro de

```
'items' => array(
  array ('description' => 'piscina de bolinha',
  'quantity' => '1',
  'item_id' => '1',
  'price_cents' => '1012'), // em centavos
```

Meu HTML

```
<form action="dados.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="description[]" placeholder="descrição"><br>
    <input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantidade"><br>
    <input type="text" name="item_id[]" placeholder="id do item"><br>
    <input type="text" name="price_cents[]" placeholder="preço"><br>
    <input type="text" name="description[]" placeholder="descrição"><br>
    <input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantidade"><br>
    <input type="text" name="item_id[]" placeholder="id do item"><br>
    <input type="text" name="price_cents[]" placeholder="preço"><br>
    <input type="text" name="description[]" placeholder="descrição"><br>
    <input type="text" name="quantity[]" placeholder="quantidade"><br>
    <input type="text" name="item_id[]" placeholder="id do item"><br>
    <input type="text" name="price_cents[]" placeholder="preço"><br>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Utilize índices no seu HTML. Ex: `description[0]`, `description[1]`; `quantity[0]`, `quantity[1]` etc.  Ou utilize `items[0][description]`, `items[0][quantity]`; `items[1][description]`, `items[1][quantity]` e depois envie os dados e veja como eles chegam no PHP.

Comment: Show @ValdeirPsr, vou fazer esta sugestão!

Comment: Show @ValdeirPsr, mas os valores serão dinâmicos como posso saber? Ex.: Cliente 1 selecionou 2 exames description[ ], quantity[ ], item_id[ ], price_cents[ ] 2 vezes. O Cliente 2 selecionou 3 exames. Deu para entender?

Comment: @CristianoFacirolli: Não escreva *resolvido* no título da pergunta e não apresente a solução na pergunta. Para apresentar uma solução crie uma resposta. Veja [ask] e [answer]. Eu removi o texto da resposta que publicou no corpo da pergunta e passei para o campo de respostas.

Comment: Show @ValdeirPsr Obrigado pela dica e corrigido a questão!

Answer (score -2):

**Solução publicada pelo Autor da Pergunta, equivocadamente no corpo da pergunta:**

Criei um array vazio para ser preenchido com as informações que vem do formulário, após inseri esta variável dentro do array.

```
$dados = [];
for($i=0;$i < count($_POST['description']);$i++){
    $dados[] = [
    'description' => $_POST['description'][$i],
    'quantity' => $_POST['quantity'][$i], 
    'item_id' => $_POST['item_id'][$i],
    'price_cents' => $_POST['price_cents'][$i]];
}
```